# QB-core server is not working I can load in but I just cant select a location and it is a black screen

Tags: fivem

SCRIPT ERROR: citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:739: SCRIPT ERROR: @qb-core/server/player.lua:162: No such export LoadInventory in resource qb-inventory

i have updated my mysql. and all there is a blakc screen than should be my location spawn point. I can select a chericter but it just doesn't work.